# Exception in thread Unresolved compilation problems:

Tags: selenium

This is my script:

```
package sampleTests;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class AdminLogin {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(); //Launches Firefox Browser with blank url
driver.close();
}

}
```

When I run the script, am getting below error, I tried to add the java lib in Class path instead of Module path, still the issue not resolved, someone please help;

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
WebDriver cannot be resolved to a type FirefoxDriver cannot be resolved to a type at sampleTests.AdminLogin.main(AdminLogin.java:10)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the path of the Geckodriver (the executable that is used for Firefox tests using Selenium).

1. Search for `Geckodriver` in Google.
2. Download the executable as per your system (Win/Mac/Linux)
3. Set the path of the executable in your tests as given below -

   ```
   package sampleTests;

   import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
   import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

   public class AdminLogin {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver",Path_of_Firefox_Driver");

   // example for Windows
    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver",D:\\GeckoDriver\\geckodriver.exe");

   WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(); 
   driver.get("https://testautomationu.applitools.com/");
   driver.quit();
   }
   ```

   }